# Webview with flutter android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, webview, flutter-dependencies, onesignal

I have problem with flutter webview, anyone help to fix this problem?!

The plugins `onesignal_flutter, store_redirect` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing them since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

Comment: These are simply warnings for the package developers, not you.

Comment: When I try to build the apk these are the problems that are  and i cant build it